# Access the Renderer from a service

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to have a service register a callback for click events on the window. I would prefer to not access the global window object directly from my code. I tried instead to use a Renderer and register a global listener, but that fails in the browser stating there is not provider for Renderer. I use it in components, but I cannot seem to use it in a service. What is the preferred way to accomplish this?

Here is my current working approach:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor () {
    Observable.fromEvent(window, 'click').subscribe(() => console.log('window click received'));
  }
}
```

Here is what I would like to do, but it fails:

```
import { Injectable, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Observer } from 'rxjs/Observer';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor (private renderer: Renderer) {
    let clickEvent = new Observable<Event>(
      (observer: Observer<Event>) => {
        this.renderer.listenGlobal('window', 'click', (evt: Event) => 
          {
            observer.next(evt);
          })
      });
    clickEvent.subscribe(() => console.log('window click received'));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `RendererFactory2` into the service and create the new instance of Renderer2:

```js
import { Injectable, RendererFactory2, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Observer } from 'rxjs/Observer';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  private renderer: Renderer2;

  constructor (rendererFactory: RendererFactory2) {
    this.renderer = rendererFactory.createRenderer(null, null);
    let clickEvent = new Observable<Event>(
      (observer: Observer<Event>) => {
        this.renderer.listenGlobal('window', 'click', (evt: Event) => 
          {
            observer.next(evt);
          })
      });
    clickEvent.subscribe(() => console.log('window click received'));
  }
}
```